# apache installation -- change a directory's write access

Tags: apache-2.2

I am new to seutp an apache server, and right now I am setting up a bugzilla server. I followed this instruction http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/installation.html#install-bzfiles, which says

"Good locations are either directly in the web server's document directories or in /usr/local with a symbolic link to the web server's document directories or an alias in the web server's configuration. " -- so I stored the downloaded bugzilla directory into /srv/www

Next, I follow this "Once all the files are in a web accessible directory, make that directory writable by your web server's user. This is a temporary step until you run the checksetup.pl script, which locks down your installation." --- so I looked at my apache server process and found that it is running with user name of 'wwwrun' (by the way, who created this user name? I just started apache server by 'sudo rcapache2 start'), it seems that I need to use chmod to make my /srv/www/bugzilla-3.4.5 writeable by 'wwwrun', how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do a chmod or chown like this

```
 sudo chmod 0777 /srv/www/bugzilla-3.4.5
```

or alternatively do

```
 sudo chown -R wwwrun.wwwrun /srv/www/bugzilla-3.4.5
 sudo chmod 0755 /srv/www/bugzilla-3.4.5
```

Comment: the first appoach seems to leave severe security loophole, isn't it?